# sIFR 3 rev.436 is unable to sucessfully publish movie — the flash file is blank

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, sifr3

I have been trying to get sIFR 3 rev.436 working on my site but I stuck at publishing the movie. 
I did everything the instruction had told me to but when I published the movie and double clicked it to test, it failed. Yhe movie was blank with the following error. Someone said the Action Scripts should be in the same folder as the sifr.fla; it was, but it didn't help at all. 
Here's the compiler errors:

> Scene=Scene 1, layer=code, frame=1, Line 19
>   The class or interface 'sIFR' could not be loaded.

I was puzzled and after hours of looping in the situation I downloaded rev.432 and tested it out. To my delight, everything turned out right and I published the movie successfully! 
But sadly I installed re.436 in Wordpress and it wouldn't display.

Is there anyway I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Problems solved. 
Might be useful for this thread too.
[sIFR 3 r4.36 has problem with Flash 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006620/sifr-3-r4-36-has-problem-with-flash-8)

1. Locate to your sIFR Action Scripts. Edit with a text editor. Change the encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI.
2. You are done.
   Glad I found the way.